# Rendering a rect-based minimap

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d-iPhone, 1.0.1.

My game has a map. And I have an array containing `NSValues` (`CGRects`) that basically represent the collisions in the map. Anyway, what I need is to literally create a texture which is pretty much a grey background with black-filled rectangles representing my rects, and later I'll use this texture to create my minimap.

Anyway, the problem is the texture-creation part. I want to know about this, because creating `CCSprites` to represent my rectangles is a bit impossible (they're hundreds per map!). I also considered drawing primitives with stuff like `CCDrawLine` and such, but I'm not so sure about this.

What do you recommend? How would you create a texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a minimap means creating a scaled down version of whatever map you're using to represent the game world.

One approach that might work is to scale down your map layer (CCTMXTiledMap?) so it fits the size of your minimap. Then render it onto a CCRenderTexture. This may be time consuming so it's a good idea not to update the minimap render texture every frame.

Alternatively loop over your tilemap, and for each tile render a single pixel at the appropriate position onto the render texture using a given color based on the tile's type (grass, mountain, water, etc). If the resulting minimap is too large or small, place 2x2 pixels or more or scale down the rendertexture.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [tile-based game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d) to me.

Comment: Wait, no - my problem isn't about creating a tilemap. It is actually about creating a minimap based on my tilemap. What I need is a way to generate a texture (CCTexture2D) based on a set of CGRects I have.